Performance issues with pyodbc when querying from a view
I have a simple Python script that uses pyodbc to query a SQL Server database. It looks something like this:
import pyodbc

connstr = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd'
connection = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
cursor = connection.cursor()

with open('filewithquery.txt','r') as f:
    query = f.read()
    cursor.execute(query)

The query is a very simple one, it just takes the form
SELECT * FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.key1 = t2.key1 AND t1.key2 = t2.key2
WHERE datecolumn = 'literaldatetime'

When I run the query directly in SSMS it executes in about 4 seconds. When I run the Python above I give up after it sits for about half an hour. I have about a dozen queries and all of them work perfectly with this method except for this one. The result is about 1500-2000 rows and there are about 20 columns.
The only difference between this one and the other queries that I can find is that t1 and t2 are views rather than tables. Should this make a difference, and if so, is there a solution?
Note I don't have any elevated access to the database. I can run select queries only, so I can't create indexes, etc, although if it runs fine in SSMS then I doubt this is the issue.

Does same query really complete fully in SSMS in 4 seconds or do you see results but query still runs? Is your Python environment and/or SSMS local or remote to server? I.e., Do you run code on same machine or network as database?

@Parfait the query fully completes in 4 seconds. The database is remote in both cases.

So does both Python and SSMS run on same Windows machine or different remote machines?

Also, you may be simplifying items here. Please post query closer to actual. Does that .txt carry only that one simple join query? Try avoiding SELECT *. Print out query in Python and run it exactly as is in SSMS.

@Parfait yes there is only one join. The query is copied and pasted verbatim between Python and MSSMS. The query is literally just selecting about 20 columns with one join and one WHERE clause on the single column.
I am running Python and SSMS from the same machine - my laptop. The database in both cases is hosted remotely.

Are Python and SSMS using the same @@OPTIONS value? Some SET options are plan-affecting and so can cause entirely different plans to be constructed for the same query (even if the queries are byte-for-byte identical). Seems like required reading, Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?

@AlwaysLearning I am not familiar with this, so I will have a read. Thank you!
